# Webservice for Client testing

Tags: web-services, testing, client

some time ago I've read of a Webservice, that simulates a large number of clients to your Website / Webapp, which click randomly everywhere and log every error or timeout they produce with that behaviour. As far as I remember it was based on javascript.

It's like Zombie.js / Phantom.js, but only as a Service without having to do the setup self.

Does anybody know this service?

(Things I've already excluded: WebServiceStudio, Storm, SoapUi

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to test how well your webservice works. I have used JMeter which is very good.

http://jmeter.apache.org/

Comment: I want to test what errors could occur, if the user performs unexpected clicks.